# Databricks table metadata through JDBC driver

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, databricks, azure-databricks

The Spark JDBC driver (SparkJDBC42.jar) is unable to capture certain information from the below table structure:

1. table level comment
2. The TBLPROPERTIES key-value pair information
3. PARTITION BY information

However, it captures the column level comment (eg. the comment against employee_number column), all columns of employee table, their technical data types.

Please advise if I need to configure any additional properties to be ale to read/extract the information that the driver could not extract at the moment.

```sql
create table default.employee( 
  employee_number INT COMMENT ‘Unique identifier for an employee’, 
  employee_name VARCHAR(50), 
  employee_age INT)
PARTITIONED BY (employee_age) 
COMMENT ‘this is a table level comment’ 
TBLPROPERTIES (‘created.by.user’ = ‘Noor’, ‘created.date’ = ‘10-08-2021’);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to execute:

```sql
describe table extended default.employee
```

via JDBC interface as well.  In first case it will return a table with 3 columns, that you can parse into column level & table level properties - it shouldn't be very complex, as there are explicit delimiters between row-level & table level data:

[image]

You can also execute:

```sql
show create table default.employee
```

that will give you a table with one column, containing the SQL statement that you may parse:

[image]

Comment: Hello Alex, By default, the JDBC driver is sending "describe default.employee2" command to the database. Because of this, I think the extended properties are not captured. Is there a way to specify as a custom property to bring in extended properties metadata? Please note that I don't have control on writing my own commands for the JDBC driver to execute on the database.

Comment: Hmmm. I checked it yesterday with ODBC driver - everything worked just fine. The command is sent to Spark on Databricks that understands that commands